# Is there a way to inspect thin metal weld (2 mm - 3mm) by ultrasonic testing?

Tags: acoustics, material-science, metals

I am working with an ultrasonic device to inspect welds. So far, I have learned that the minimum thickness of the metal sheet for this inspection is 6mm - 8mm. But the product of mine has 3mm thick welds:

[image]

I have basic knowledge working with angle beam transducer to inspect thick metal welds. How can I inpsect thin metal welds by using conventional ultrasonic device?

Comment: What if you put a solid rubber mat between the probe and the work piece?

Answer (score 1):

If the thickness is less than 3-4 of $\lambda$ bulk waves cannot propagate (limits to min. 5-6mm). You need "normal" or so called Lamb waves, you can achieve them with a wedge sensor (inclined angle to the surface, goes definitely below 3 mm) or submerging methods (which is not really very practically).

see e.g. [Comparison of Ultrasonic Non-Contact Air-Coupled Techniques](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1944/14/5/1058/pdf)

[Lamb Wave interaction](https://www.ndt.net/article/aisha2007/papers/aisha4.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a speculation, but maybe you can place a thicker plate under your thin plate and use reflections from the bottom of the thicker plate. Reflections from the bottom of the thin plate will be a problem, so maybe some oil should be placed between the thin and thick plates to make sure more ultrasonic power gets into the thicker plate.

Comment: the angle beam will not transfer in a straight line if we put another plate under thin plate. that would be much complicated

Comment: @Dat : Part of ultrasonic power will still propagate in a straight line. I cannot be sure that this is enough, but one cannot be sure this is not enough. For example, if the plates are very smooth this will be enough.